# electronのwebviewにcssを当てる方法

Tags: electron

electronにウェブページを埋め込み、そこへ独自のスタイルを割り当てるにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

メソッドが用意されています。

http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.8/api/web-view-tag/#webviewinsertcsscss

WebViewを埋め込んだHTMLファイル内で実行されるjavascript内で、WebViewのDOMオブジェクトを取得し、上記のメソッドを利用すれば良いでしょう。

```
<html>
  <body>
    <webview id="webview" src="~~~" />
    <script>
      var webview = document.getElementById('webview');
      webview.insertCSS("~~~");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

また、BrowserWindowに直接`loadURL`で指定した場合でも、BrowserWindowが持っているwebContentsを利用すれば同様の処理が可能です。

```
var win = new BrowserWindow(width: 800, height: 600);
win.loadURL("~~~");
win.webContents.insertCSS("~~~");
```